# Accessing remote kibana/ES from client : time out

Tags: linux, debian, vps, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to access kibana/elastic search on a VPS from my computer.

On the VPS if I

```
curl -XGET 'http://SERVERIP:9200'
```

I get a good answer from ES, and same with Kibana.

On my computer, if I use the same commands I get timed out (for both kibana and ES) :

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to SERVERIP port 9200: Connection timed
>   out

Server runs Debian 8.

I think server is rejecting client connection so I did

```
sudo netstat -tulpen
```

To try to understand why.

For ES and kibana I have

> tcp        0      0 SERVERIP:5601        0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      111        19051      1832/node
>   tcp6       0      0
>   SERVERIP:9200        :::*                    LISTEN      110        19054      1784/java

Which I think means that anyone should be able to curl SERVERIP:5601.
I don't know about

> :::*

for ES tho.

Server also runs a apache2 server for an html website which adress is SERVERIP.

kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml have server.host = SERVERIP

Comment: sounds like a firewall issue

Comment: @Mike Hey thank you for answering. I didn't install a firewall. Is it possible that VPS provider blocks these ports silently ?

Comment: its possible there's a firewall for your VPS on the providers consol/portal

Comment: @Mike Going to look into it. Will update. ty

Comment: @Mike It was because of firewall of local wifi distributor. Do you want to add an answer ?

Comment: added a generic answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure there is no firewall of your provider or device in from of the server.